# android listview in fragment can not define adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

I try to make listview in fragment and load the data from database. But I have no idea with this :( I got some red cross and don't know how to fix it. I got the sourcode its self from extend Activity not fragment :(
anyone can help me??

here is the code

```
public class FragmentaReviews extends SherlockFragment {

private SimpleAdapter adpt;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_main, container,
            false);


    adpt  = new SimpleAdapter(new ArrayList<Review>(), this);
    ListView lView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lView.setAdapter(adpt);

    // Exec async load task
    (new AsyncListViewLoader()).execute("http://10.0.3.2/text.php");
return rootView;
}


private class AsyncListViewLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Review>> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Review> result) {         
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        adpt.setItemList(result);
        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {     
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Downloading Reviews...");
        dialog.show();          
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Review> doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<Review> result = new ArrayList<Review>();

        try {
            URL u = new URL(params[0]);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Read the stream
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while ( is.read(b) != -1)
                baos.write(b);

            String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp);
            for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                result.add(convertReview(arr.getJSONObject(i)));
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Review convertReview(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        String id = obj.getString("id");
        String name = obj.getString("name");



        return new Review(id, name);
    }

}
```

}

red cross in

```
adpt  = new SimpleAdapter(new ArrayList<Review>(), this);
```

---

```
adpt.setItemList(result);
```

here's the adapter

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Review> {

private List<Review> itemList;
private Context context;

public SimpleAdapter(List<Review> itemList, Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = ctx;     
}

public int getCount() {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.size();
    return 0;
}

public Review getItem(int position) {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.get(position);
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.get(position).hashCode();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta_review, null);
    }


    Review c = itemList.get(position);

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
    text.setText(c.getid());

    TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    text1.setText(c.getname());




    return v;

}

public List<Review> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public void setItemList(List<Review> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}

}
```

Comment: When you say a red cross, do you mean in Eclipse? If so, try doing a Project Clean, then rebuild.

Comment: i've tried.. but it got red cross because "The constructor SimpleAdapter(ArrayList<Review>, FragmentaReviews) is undefined" and "The method setItemList(List<Review>) is undefined for the type SimpleAdapter"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your constructor for SimpleAdapter takes, as its second argument, a Context object. The 'this' you are passing in is not therefore a context object (such as an Activity) so you must pass in a context object instead. The 'this' is referring to your FragmentReviews class. You may be able to use this.getActivity() as the second argument of the constructor. You may have to change your code to something like this:

```
Context ctx = (Context)(this.getActivity());
adpt  = new SimpleAdapter(new List<Review>(), ctx);
```

Your constructor uses a List object but you are calling it using an ArrayList object.

Comment: so I need to change --> adpt  = new SimpleAdapter(new ArrayList<Review>(), this); into adpt  = new SimpleAdapter(new ArrayList<Review>(), this.getActivity(); ??

Comment: hmm.. my class extend is SherlockFragment .. it looks like can't use this.getActivity() which is for fragmentactivity..

Comment: Yes. I haven't used the ActionBar Sherlock package myself but all Fragments have the .getActivity() method - if you find this doesn't work, then you'll need to cast it e.g. Context ctx = (Context)(this.getActivity()); and use that.

Comment: hmm I'm newbie in android.. So would you like to give me more specific instruction??

Comment: should I change Context into something? Because when I put it.. I got this "Multiple markers at this line
 - Context cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - Context cannot be resolved 
  to a type"

Comment: If you can't resolve the Context type, you've got some major problems. Try adding the import statement import android.content.Context but it might be that your Eclipse project is not an Android project, just a Java project.

Comment: I've tried to import it and got this in red cross "The constructor SimpleAdapter(ArrayList<Review>, Context) is undefined" --> adpt  = new SimpleAdapter(new ArrayList<Review>(), ctx);

Comment: You should use a List<Review> object when instantiating it. See my amended answer.

Comment: still got red cross.. :(
 - Cannot instantiate the type List<Review>
 - The constructor SimpleAdapter(List<Review>, Context) is 
  undefined